# Python list comprehension for the given code

Tags: python, list-comprehension, nested-loops

Can I use list comprehension or reduce a `for` loop for the code?

```
x=[100,200,300]
y=[10,20,50,70,80]
results=[]
for i in range(len(x)):
    temp=[]
    for j in range(len(y)):
        x[i]+=y[j]
        temp.append(x[i])
    results.append(temp)
print(results)
```

Comment: `x` isn't defined in the snippet you shared.

Comment: I'm sorry sir, I've added x now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python 3.8 added a neat feature of [assignment expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) which is really handy in producing cumulative sums, and can help you replace these loops in a couple of list comprehensions:

```py
total = 0
cumsums = [total := total + t for t in y]
result = [[c+s for c in cumsums]  for s in x]
```